# Notepad++ Regex Mark

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like this

```
randomtext.html
file1
file1
file2
```

I want to mark the first line after the line ended with html. So, it should marked the first "file1" only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with:

Within `Mark tab`

Find what: `html\R\K.+`

Be sure you haven't chck `. matches newline` and check `Mark lines` then click on <kbd>Find All</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
html  : Literally html
\R    : any kind of line break (ie. \n or \r or \r\n)
\K    : forget everything found before
.+    : Everything until the next line break. (ie. the second line).
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. In depth explanation will be mush appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would like to ask what do you mean by mark?

Press ctrl+h. Select regular expression and you can use following regular expression:-

**Find:** (.* )html\r\n(.*)\r\n(.*)

**Replace:** $1html\r\n-------$2\r\n$3

Here i have use '-------' as the mark, you can put the mark according to your need.

Comment: There is a tab in Notepad++ called "Mark". So, you can bookmark a line which match the RegEx. Unfortunately, your expression didn't work in my case